# Patching a method without changing how the method works?

Tags: python, pandas, mocking, patch

I'm trying to test that a pandas method gets called with some values.

However, just by applying a @patch decorator causes the patched method to throw a `ValueError` within pandas, when the actual method does not. I'm just trying to test that `Stock.calc_sma` is calling the underlying `pandas.rolling_mean` function.

I'm under the assumption that the `@patch` decorator basically adds some "magic" methods to the thing I'm patching that allow me to check if the function was called. If this is the case, why doesn't the `pandas.rolling_mean` function behave the same whether it's patched vs. not patched?

app/models.py

```
import pandas as pd
class Stock:  # i've excluded a bunch of class methods, including the one that sets self.data, which is a DataFrame of stock prices.
    def calc_sma(self, num_days)
        if self.data.shape[0] > num_days:  # Stock.data holds a DataFrame of stock prices
                column_title = 'sma' + str(num_days)
                self.data[column_title] = pd.rolling_mean(self.data['Adj Close'], num_days)
```

app/tests/TestStockModel.py

```
def setUp(self):
    self.stock = MagicMock(Stock)
    self.stock.ticker = "AAPL"
    self.stock.data = DataFrame(aapl_test_data.data)

@patch('app.models.pd.rolling_mean')
def test_calc_sma(self, patched_rolling_mean):
    Stock.calc_sma(self.stock, 3)
    assert(isinstance(self.stock.data['sma3'], Series))
    patched_rolling_mean.assert_any_call()
```

### ERROR: test_calc_sma (TestStockModel.TestStockModel)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/grant/Code/python/chartflux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/grant/Code/python/chartflux/app/tests/TestStockModel.py", line 26, in test_calc_sma
    Stock.calc_sma(self.stock, 3)
  File "/Users/grant/Code/python/chartflux/app/models.py", line 27, in calc_sma
    self.data[column_title] = pd.rolling_mean(self.data['Adj Close'], num_days)
  File "/Users/grant/Code/python/chartflux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1887, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/Users/grant/Code/python/chartflux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1967, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "/Users/grant/Code/python/chartflux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2017, in _sanitize_column
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of '
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/'
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> with patch('os.getcwd'):
...     print(os.getcwd)
...     print(os.getcwd())
...     print(len(os.getcwd()))
...
<MagicMock name='getcwd' id='4472112296'>
<MagicMock name='getcwd()' id='4472136928'>
0
```

By default `patch` replaces things with really generic mock objects. As you can see, calling the mock just returns another mock. It has a `len` of 0 even if the replaced object wouldn't have a `len`. Its attributes are also generic mocks.

So to simulate behavior requires things extra arguments like:

```
>>> with patch('os.getcwd', return_value='/a/wonderful/place'):
...     os.getcwd()
...
'/a/wonderful/place'
```

Or to "pass through":

```
>>> _cwd = os.getcwd
>>> with patch('os.getcwd') as p:
...     p.side_effect = lambda: _cwd()
...     print(os.getcwd())
...
/
```

There is a similar example in https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the info @jason-s! I ran into another problem entirely after this, but I'll leave that to another question :)

Comment: What if the patched method has arguments ? Isn't there something built-in for just checking if a function was called without changing its argument ?