# Check if function was called without changing its behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I test that a python function was called, **without changing its behavior at all** ?

There are many related posts but I could not find one of them that covers it all:

- [How to test that a function is called within a function with nosetests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762293/how-to-test-that-a-function-is-called-within-a-function-with-nosetests) (changes behavior)
- [Patching a method without changing how the method works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097061/patching-a-method-without-changing-how-the-method-works) (doesnt work with arguments and return values)

Basically, I just need to spy the function to know whether or not it was called.

For instance, the following snippet has extremely surprising behavior

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def func(a,b):
    print('was called')
    return a * b

with patch('test.func') as patched_function:
    print(func(4,5))

print(patched_function.called)
```

Output:

```
<MagicMock name='func()' id='1721737249456'>
True
was called
20
False
```

While I was only expecting

```
was called
20
True
```

Comment: Use a global variable that you set to `True` upon first call ?

Comment: Does't work if `func` is inside a module that you can't modify, which is almost always what you're looking for when patching

Comment: You can also use a global variable that acts as a counter for the number of times a function is called. Something like: `def func(i): i+=1`

Comment: I cannot modify `func`, it's not in my codebase. See my comment above

Answer (score 0):

You should create a decorator for the function like so:

```
class CheckCall(object):
    called = False

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self *args, **kwargs):
        self.called = True
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can apply your decorator like so

```
with patch('test.func') as patched_function:
    patched_function = CheckCall(patched_function)
    print(patched_function.called) # Prints False
    patched_function(...)
    print(patched_function.called) # Prints True
```

Comment: I thought it would be already implemented in unittest. If there are no answers using unittest I'll accept yours